# No such file or directory error on a mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, bufferedreader, readfile

I'm trying to read a file that exists in the following location of my Eclipse java project:

Tester -> src -> threads -> ReadFile.java

This is the code used:

public class Tester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReadFile[] readers;
    readers = new ReadFile[3];

    for (int intLoopCounter = 0; intLoopCounter < 3; intLoopCounter++) {
        readers[intLoopCounter] = 
                new ReadFile("ReadFile.java", intLoopCounter);

        System.out.println("Doing thread number: " + (intLoopCounter + 1));
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what to add to:

```
new ReadFile("ReadFile.java"
```

so the file can be read?

There is a buffered reader in the ReadFile.java class file. I'm experimenting with this just to see if I can read the ReafFile.java file and show the results to the console.

Here is the code that is throwing the error from ReadFile.java:

```
public ReadFile(String filename, int i) {
    id = i;

    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Problem occured: " + e.getMessage());

    } // catch
} // Constructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Tester is your project root directory, your path to the file should be `"src/threads/ReadFile.java"`. If the file trully exists it will be found.

Comment: Thanks everyone for such quick replies. Your code located the file. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the path in the call to `ReadFile` to include a full path, a path anchored by your user directory, or a path relative to the directory in which Eclipse runs your test program.

For example, if your project is located in `/Users/myuser/projects/Tester/src/threads`, you can use this line:

```
new ReadFile("/Users/myuser/projects/Tester/src/threads/ReadFile.java", intLoopCounter)
```